# A "Euler" difference equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

I'm currently reading a non-math paper that contains the following system of recursive equations:
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}-x_{n+2} = c (x_n- x_{n+1}), n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
where all $x_n$ and $c$ are real numbers.
There is no initial value given. The paper then says that this is "Euler" and easily seen to be solved by $x_{n+1}=cx_n$.
Indeed it is easily seen that this is a solution, but in what sense is this equation Euler?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler

Answer (score 0):

The splution of
$$X_{n+1}-X_{n+2}=c(X_n-X_{n+1})\implies Y_{n+1}=c Y_n \implies Y_n= c^n D$$
$$\implies X_{n}-X_{n+1} =c^n D$$ by telescopinc summation we get
$$x_1-X_{n+1}=c\frac{c^n-1}{c-1} D\implies X_n=x_1-\frac{c^n-c}{c-1}$$

Sorry I don't really know if it is called Euler equation. But I will not be surprised if it is true. Why doesn't the OP share the context with us.